# How do I convert json representation of exception, back to c# exception?

Tags: c#, json

I have a asp.net application, where I am logging some exceptions into json format.

Here is a example of a exception that happened in my system, and was logged:

```
    "ex" : {
        "ClassName" : "System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Okq8.Okq8.Integrations.Emric.BlancoCLAS.EmricFaultValidation]",
        "Message" : "Exception of type EmricInfoValidationException: Caught service fault System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Emric.CommonData.ServiceFaults.Version2011_10.EmricFaultValidation, Emric.CommonData.ServiceFaults, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=39f408d8507c12cf]] in method Emric.Services.ApplyWorkflowService.DataAccess, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3b8d6ba72c2815b.CreateCreditApplication\nException of type EmricInfoValidationException: Caught service fault System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Emric.CommonData.ServiceFaults.Version2011_10.EmricFaultValidation, Emric.CommonData.ServiceFaults, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=39f408d8507c12cf]] in method ApplyPersistenceService.ValidateCreditApplicationInformation\nException of type EmricInfoValidationException: EmricInfoValidationException in BusinessRulesService\nException of type FaultException`1: Exception of type EmricInfoValidationException: EmricInfoValidationException in BusinessRulesService\nException of type FaultException`1: Exception of type EmricInfoValidationException: Caught service fault System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Emric.CommonData.ServiceFaults.Version2011_10.EmricFaultValidation, Emric.CommonData.ServiceFaults, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=39f408d8507c12cf]] in method ApplyPersistenceService.ValidateCreditApplicationInformation\nException of type EmricInfoValidationException: EmricInfoValidationException in BusinessRulesService\nException of type FaultException`1: Exception of type EmricInfoValidationException: EmricInfoValidationException in BusinessRulesService",
        "Data" : null,
        "InnerException" : null,
        "HelpURL" : null,
        "StackTraceString" : "   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Okq8.Okq8.Integrations.Emric.BlancoCLAS.CLASGateway.<CreateVisaApplicationAsync>d__22.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Code\\Source\\Okq8.Okq8.Integrations.Emric\\BlancoCLAS\\CLASGateway.cs:line 131\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Okq8.Okq8.Integrations.Emric.BlancoCLAS.CLASGateway.<CreateVisaApplicationAsync>d__22.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Code\\Source\\Okq8.Okq8.Integrations.Emric\\BlancoCLAS\\CLASGateway.cs:line 142\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Okq8.Okq8.BusinessLogic.SwedishBank.ICLASManagerOkq8.<>c__DisplayClass30_1.<<StartCardApplication>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Code\\Source\\Okq8.Okq8.BusinessLogic\\SwedishBank\\ICLASManagerOkq8.cs:line 216",
        "RemoteStackTraceString" : null,
        "RemoteStackIndex" : 0,
        "ExceptionMethod" : "8\nHandleReply\nSystem.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel\nVoid HandleReply(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyRpc ByRef)",
        "HResult" : -2146233087,
        "Source" : "System.ServiceModel",
        "WatsonBuckets" : null,
        "code" : [ 
            {}
        ],
        "reason" : [ 
            {}
        ],
        "messageFault" : null,
        "action" : "http://www.example.org/a/long/url",
        "detail" : {
            "ValidationItems" : [ 
                {
                    "Culture" : null,
                    "MessageBody" : "Ange mailadress på formen namn@exampel.com för sökande: XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "MessageHeader" : "Felaktigt format på email"
                }, 
                {
                    "Culture" : null,
                    "MessageBody" : "Please input in format name@example.com for applicant: XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "MessageHeader" : "Wrong format of email"
                }
            ],
            "FaultCode" : -1610350577,
            "FaultMessages" : [ 
                {
                    "MessageBody" : "Lägg till saknade uppgifter och rätta felaktigheter innan du fortsätter.",
                    "MessageHeader" : "Uppgifter saknas eller är felaktiga."
                }
            ],
            "FaultSource" : "ApplyWorkflowExternalClientService"
        }
    }
```

Now, I need to do some work where I sanitize/manipulate some of the fields here, and I would like to be able to work with this exact exception in c# as a Exception object.

Is there any way that I can do this? reading the json directly from a hardcoded string would be fine

Comment: Exception classes are not simple objects. A lot of this data isn't settable, so you can't turn this JSON into an `Exception`

Comment: Have you tried simply deserialising it? But as Liam mentions it almost certainly isn't that straightforward. However, why would you need to do that anyway?? If this is a logged exception, surely you don't need to re-throw it? What are you actually trying to achieve by this? It might make more sense to have a simple class you deserialise to, containing the properties that you need to work with.

Comment: You are very likely going to need to get very familiar with creating objects and setting properties with *Reflection*.  `Activator.CreateInstance` can create the object, then get the properties for the type (as `PropertyInfo` objects)  using Reflection.  Once you have them , set them by setting the values of the PropertyInfos

Comment: Because the exception is logged, I need to sanitize away some the the information, the part that says "XXX" is personal data, which i cannot log. Therefore, I would like to have a example exception object with some nested values that I can see if I can manipulate

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove that **before** you log it?

Comment: Yes, thats what I need to be able to do going forward, but right now I need a method for sanitizing future exceptions that might get logged.
I'm not able to trigger the exact exception again, since it rendered from a external API, therefore I need to be able to recreate an exception that is already logged

Comment: Sanitizing away PII from free-form text like *"Ange mailadress på formen namn@exampel.com för sökande: XXXXXXXXXX"* will not be easy.  How do you recognize that it's PII and not just text (for example, most sanitizers would pick up your sample email address (*namn@exampel.com*) as something to eliminate

Comment: because XXXXXXX is actually not a string of X'es, but a social security-number that I have censored away for this post